# What Is The Easiest Way To Split ETC from ETH in 2017

Tags: mist, wallets, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereum-classic

I am not very technical. I want to know if there is an easier way to split eth from etc without using the mist wallet 0.8.1 in 2017.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "easy".

This article gives a very simple step by step guide for how to split your ETH from your ETC.

https://steemit.com/ethereum/@pauls/ethereum-fork-step-by-step-guide-to-safely-splitting-your-eth-etc

---

If by easy you mean as few steps as possible http://selletcsafely.tech/ offers a service to generate a transaction. I can't vouch for the service beyond only that it exists.

**Test with small amounts**

Answer (score 1):

In 2017 after EIP155 you can simply make two transactions, one on each chain. Ensure that you are using the latest MIST wallet which I am assuming is on the ETH chain.

A) Use your standard ETH wallet and transfer to a new ETH account
B) Go to https://classicetherwallet.com and create a new account. Make sure that you record or save all credentials for this account.
C) Go back to https://classicetherwallet.com an open a wallet by uploading your keyfile from your GETH installation (or private key that you exported from your original wallet), You will see that your account still contains ETC. Transfer the ETC to the new ETC account that you created in (B)

It works - I have just done it. But be cautious. Transfer a small amount first.

Comment: Beware that this risks your entire ETC balance. Does not matter what amount you send if random website has your private.

Comment: myEtherWallet & classicEtherWallet do not access your keys - they remain in javascript in your browser. If, of course, you have a keylogger, you are screwed anyway.

Comment: Assuming you trust the authors of both. I'm sure they are perfectly reputable, but I think it's worth reminding users that you should be damned sure what you're doing when you c/p your pk.